# Mostrar somente a ultima palavra de uma string

Tags: c, string

O intuito do programa é ler uma *string*, ex:

**ler** - Jose Da Silva 
**printar** - Silva

Ou seja, sempre *printar* a última palavra da *string*.

Minha lógica foi ler a *string* de trás para frente, e ao encontrar o primeiro espaço parar o laço.

No exemplo acima, rodando no meu programa ficaria:

1 - Ler - Jose Da Silva 
2 - Guardava numa *string* auxiliar a "avliS"  
3 - Depois eu crio outro laço e leio de trás para frente a *string* auxiliar que teria "avliS" guardado 
4 - De trás para frente ficaria "Silva"

E por fim eu mostro a *string* auxiliar que terá exatamente a ultima palavra da *string* Digitada.

**Atual situação do meu código:**

Meu código esta conseguindo ler a *string* de trás para frente e parar no primeiro (espaço) que ele encontrar. Mas não sei como fazer para criar uma *string* auxiliar que receba caractere a caractere a última palavra da primeira *string* (invertida), e depois inverter essa *string* auxiliar.

OBS: Estou disposto a ver outras lógicas (que podem ser mais fácies que a minha) para a resolução desse problema.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (){
    char frase[200];
    int i;

    scanf(" %[^\n]s", frase);

    for (i=strlen(frase)-1;i> -1;i--){
        if (frase[i] == ' '){
            break;
        }

        printf("%c",frase[i]);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Tem alguma restrição do que pode usar?

Comment: Não, mas o interessante seria algo que não ultrapassa-se muito o conhecimento de um iniciante em programação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lógica é um pouco diferente da proposta por você, mas funciona e (acho que seja) mais simples (apesar que ele lê a frase inteira, através do outro método só leria a palavra em si).

Você vai copiando cada `char` da frase principal em outro `array` de `char`, ao encontrar algum espaço, você "zera" aquele `array`, já que ao ter um espaço sabemos que não é a última palavra, no fim da string ele vai estar com a última palavra guardada, aí é só finalizar o `array` com `\0` e imprimir.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){
    char frase[200], palavra[50] = "";
    int i, j = 0;

    scanf(" %[^\n]s", frase);

    for(i = 0; frase[i] != '\0'; i++){
        palavra[j] = frase[i]; //usei o contador j em palavra pois ele poderá ser zerado ao encontrar espaço
        if(palavra[j] == ' ') //se encontrar espaço você começa uma nova palavra, mas continua onde parou na frase
            j = 0; 
        else //se não, você incrementa em j
            j++;
    }

    palavra[j] = '\0'; //finaliza o array e depois só imprimir

    printf("%s", palavra);
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Corrigi o laço como o Maniero sugeriu lá em baixo, fazer `strlen()` a todo laço realmente ia gastar processamento, enquanto for diferente de `\0` (enquanto não for fim da frase) fica melhor mesmo.

Comment: Achei legal, ficou mais simples.

Comment: @Erick, essa lógica realmente fica mais simples, mas acho que a do outro comentário economizaria processamento por ler apenas a última palavra, como é um algoritmo simples não deve fazer diferença, de qualquer maneira se alguma das respostas respondeu sua pergunta você pode aceitar a resposta pra ajudar outros usuários (e quem respondeu também kkkk)

Comment: Como faço para aceitar  a resposta ?  Não sou expert no site ainda.

Comment: @Erick, tem um "V" ao lado da resposta, clicando nele você aceita aquela resposta como a correta, isso ajuda outros usuários ao saber qual a resposta e ajuda quem respondeu

Answer (score 5):

A forma mais simples, correta e mais performática seria esta:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    char frase[200], palavra[200];
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", frase);
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; frase[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        palavra[j] = frase[i];
        j = palavra[j] == ' ' && frase[i + 1] != ' ' && frase[i + 1] != '\0' ? 0 : j + 1;
    }
    palavra[j] = '\0';
    printf("%s", palavra);
}
```

Mas se a performance for mais importante tem um jeito ainda melhor:

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jOsmHc). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rzaqwmzt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/GetLastWord.c). (note os espaços em branco adicionais no começo, meio e fim).

Estou considerando que pode ter uma só palavra enorme, por isso mantive o tamanho da palavra igual ao da frase.

Quando usa o `strlen()` precisa varrer a *string* toda pra depois varrer de novo, e isto obviamente é uma coisa ruim, então estou parando o laço quando encontrar o terminador.

Vai copiando caractere por caractere da `frase` para uma `palavra`.

Quando existe uma decisão em alterar o valor de uma mesma variável de uma forma ou de outra se uma condição for verdadeira ou falsa, costuma ser melhor usar o operador condicional (acho que é uma boa aprender, porque praticamente é só mudança de sintaxe, o conceito de condição você já entende).

A condição tem que determinar se deve zerar o contador do *array* da palavra (`j`) deve ser incrementado. Se não for incrementado deve ser zerado, ou seja, esquece tudo o que estava guardando e começa de novo no *array* da palavra. Mas tem umas pegadinhas aí.

Se for um espaço em branco, teoricamente deve zerar o contador porque começa uma palavra nova. Mas na verdade a palavra só começa se o próximo for um caractere não branco. Então além de ser um branco o próximo deve ser um não branco.

E também não pode ter o terminar (caractere nulo `\0`), já que isto afetaria o contador do índice de `palavra` e precisamos saber onde ele está para colocar o terminador.

Se estas condições não forem observadas, espaços em branco adicionais dão resultado errado.

Precisamos colocar um terminador no *array*  que recebe a palavra, caso contrário dele potencial não terá fim e acessar memória que não deve.

Aí imprime a palavra de acordo com o selecionado. Mas tem um defeito porque se tiver espaço no final o espaço será impresso. Dá para arrumar isto, mas não tinha nada na pergunta que indicasse que precisa.

outra falha é se encontrar uma tabulação ou outro caractere em branco que separe palavras, ou se encontrar um símbolo separador, como a pontuação (`,`, `.`, `?`, etc.), mas ela pode estar sendo usada de forma de a não separar palavras, então tudo fica muito mais complicado de resolver.

Mas se não for importante verificar esses casos de espaços adicionais, então uma linha resolve:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
    char frase[200];
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", frase);
    printf("%s\n", strrchr(frase, ' ') + 1);
}
```

A função [`strrchr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr) justamente pega o último bloco separado por algum caractere.